# removing null rows, where columns are dynamically subselected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with high number of value columns which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ("timestamp" timestamp PRIMARY KEY, "a" real, "b" real, "c" real)
```

The table may contain a dynamic number of value columns (like a,b,c).

I need to delete rows with where all values are null, but timestamp is not null.

I am unable to build a select query which will return null rows only.

Doing something like:

```
select * 
from tbl 
where tbl is null
```

will not work, because timestamp is not null

I tried to take the following working example:

```
select * 
from tbl 
where not (a,b,c) is null
```

and add a subselect to it:

```
select * 
from tbl 
where not (
    SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',')
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name   = 'tbl' and column_name != 'timestamp'
) is null
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `"timestamp"` is a horrible name for a column (and using a timestamp as a primary key seems dubious as well)

Comment: What's the problem with using timestamp as a PK (except the naming)? It's a time-series data.

Comment: You are limited to the resolution of the timestamp data type. Are you sure you can never, ever have two "events" that occur at exactly the same time?

Comment: Not only I am sure, I want to explicitly prevent insertion of duplicate timestamps, which in my case will make the data inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the row to a JSONB object, remove the "timestamp" column and then check for an empty value:

```
select *
from tbl 
where jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(tbl) - 'timestamp') = '{}'::jsonb;
```

This can directly be used to delete the rows:

```
delete from tbl
where jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(tbl) - 'timestamp') = '{}'::jsonb);
```

Comment: Interesting approach I didn't though of. But what would be a performance penalty for converting rows to jsonb? The table may be huge.....

Comment: @Miro: the performance of the DELETE most probably overshadows the time it takes to convert the rows to JSONB.